# Finding the indexes of specific strings in an array, using a differently ordered equivalent array, ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, loops, bioinformatics

I have two arrays: fasta_ids & frags_by_density. Both contain the same set of ≈1300 strings.
fasta_ids is ordered numerically e.g. ['frag1', 'frag2', 'frag3'...]
frags_by_density contains the same strings ordered differently e.g. ['frag14', 'frag1000'...]

The way in which frag_by_density is ordered is irrelevant to the question (but for any bioinformaticians, the 'frags' are contigs ordered by snp density).

What I want to do is find the indexes in the frag_by_density array, that contain each of the strings in fasta_ids. I want to end up with a new array of those positions (indexes), which will be in the same order as the fasta_ids array.

For example, if the order of the 'frag' strings was identical in both the fasta_ids and frags_by_density arrays, the output array would be: [0, 1, 2, 3...]. 
In this example, the value at index 2 of the output array (2), corresponds to the value at index 2 of fasta_ids ('frag3') - so I can deduce from this that the 'frag3' string is at index 2 in frags_by_density.

Below is the code I have come up with, at the moment it gets stuck in what I think is an infinite loop. I have annotated what each part should do:

```
x = 0 #the value of x will represent the position (index) in the density array
position_each_frag_id_in_d = [] #want to get positions of the values in frag_ids in frags_by_density
iteration = []
fasta_ids.each do |i|
    if frags_by_density[x] == i
        position_each_frag_id_in_d << x #if the value at position x matches the value at i, add it to the new array
        iteration << i
    else
        until frags_by_density[x] == i #otherwise increment x until they do match, and add the position
            x +=1
        end
        position_each_frag_id_in_d << x
        iteration << i
    end
    x = iteration.length # x should be incremented, however I cannot simply do: x += 1, as x may have been incremented by the until loop
end
puts position_each_frag_id_in_d
```

This was quite a complex question to put into words. Hopefully there is a much easier solution, or at least someone can modify what I have started.

**Update:** renamed the array fasta_ids, as it is in the code (sorry if any confusion)
            fasta_id = frag_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non optimized version. `array.index(x)` returns index of x in array or nil if not found. `compact` then removes nil elements from the array.

`position_of_frag_id_in_d = frag_ids.map{|x| frag_by_density.index(x)}.compact`

Comment: why the compact? surely if there are any `nil` elements then they should be left in?

Comment: if an element in `frag_id` is not found in `frag_by_density`, its position is `nil` so I remove it. OP can you post a non-trivial example to make the expected answer more clear.

Comment: Works perfectly. Yes the compact was an unnecessary but harmless addition, there wasn't going to be any nil positions as both arrays contain the same strings, so all would be found. Thanks for the help.